# Require Language In PostgreSQL Extension Control File

Tags: postgresql, plpython, postgresql-extensions

I'm developing a custom extension that uses plpythonu in several functions. I'd like to be able to require that plpythonu be installed in order to create my extension, but I don't see anything in the documentation about requiring a language via the control file.

I tried adding plpythonu to the 'requires' statement in the control file but it looks for an extension named plpythonu rather than the language.

Can this be done?

Comment: Not as far as I know. Propose it on pgsql-hackers

Comment: Starting from PostgreSQL 9.1, most languages are installed as extensions. So unless you're working on 9.0, adding plpythonu as an extension might just work. Note [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createlanguage.html)

Comment: @Kassandry unfortunately it doesn't work. The workaround I devised is to include a call to parse whether the language already exists and then CREATE LANGUAGE if it doesn't. A bit of a hack, but it seems to be working.